# Stringify enum flags

Tags: typescript

I've got a problem with stringifying and parsing enum flags. I have my enum that looks like that:

```
enum CookieOptions {
  None = 0,
  Necessary = 1 << 0,
  Analytical = 1 << 1,
  Marketing = 1 << 2,
  Parsonalisation = 1 << 3,
  All = ~(~0 << 4),
}
```

and I'd like to store it as a string (eg. in cookie or localStorage or whatever)... well converting it to string will just cast it to a number (integer), but how can I parse it so I can still use it like:

```
if (options & CookieOptions.Analytical) {
  ...
}
```

so basically how to convert an integer to flag enum?

Comment: A flag enum is just an integer behind the scenes anyway, I'm not sure I understand the problem. You'd just compare the number to your desired flag `if((options & CookieOptions.Analytical) === CookieOptions.Analytical) { ... }` (Assuming `options` is the stored number)

Comment: Please [edit] to provide a [mre] that demonstrates your issue. Right now the part you're talking about is missing... are you storing/retrieving `options`? Then please show it. Then we can say "oh just write `const options = Number(blargh())` instead of `const options = blargh()` and it will work because numeric enums are just numbers at runtime.  But right now it's not 100% clear that's the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's worth knowing what TypeScript does behind the scenes when you define an enum. It's not only declaring a type, it does also create an object emitted in the JavaScript target code. In your case that object is equivalent to:

```
var CookieOptions = {
  None: 0,
  Necessary: 1 << 0,
  Analytical: 1 << 1,
  Marketing: 1 << 2,
  Parsonalisation: 1 << 3,
  All: ~(~0 << 4),
  [0]: 'None',
  [1 << 0]: 'Necessary',
  [1 << 1]: 'Analytical',
  [1 << 2]: 'Marketing',
  [1 << 3]: 'Parsonalisation',
  [~(~0 << 4)]: 'All',
};
```

(Notice the bidirectional mapping - you can get the name from the value, as well as the value for the name. If several names map to the same value, the name you get back is pretty much arbitrary.)

This means that really, `CookieOptions.Necessary` etc. *are* just numbers. TypeScript may typecheck them as if they are something more special, but that's all it is.

In addition, TypeScript has no way of knowing which combinations of flags within an enum are valid and which aren't. It assumes you know what you are doing when you do (for example) `CookieOptions.Necessary | CookieOptions.Analytical` and allows the result of that operation to itself be of type `CookieOptions`, but in reality it may not be, and this is just accepted for convenience's sake. To put it another way, **flag enums are one part of TypeScript that is *not* strongly typed.**

So, there is no need to "convert an integer to flag enum" -- it already is one. Depending on the situation you might need to tell TypeScript that, by explicit casting:

```
var copts = 3 as CookieOptions;
// var copts: CookieOptions = 3; would be an error
```

---

On the other hand, if you *do* want to get the names of flags as an array of strings, you can use the fact that the enum is an object as described above and use a helper function, something like this:

```
function getFlagNames<E extends {[value: number]: string}>(e: E, v: number) {
  let names: string[] = [];
  while (v !== 0) {
    const topBit = 1 << (31 - Math.clz32(v));
    names.unshift(e[topBit]);
    v &= ~topBit;
  }
  return names;
}

// Example:
console.log(getFlagNames(CookieOptions, CookieOptions.Necessary | CookieOptions.Marketing));
// => ["Necessary", "Marketing"]
```

Note that it is necessary to pass in `CookieOptions` itself. Also note that this will only get a meaningful result if there *is* an enum value for every flag bit set in `v`.

Similarly, here is a helper function that will let you get a flags value given the enum object and an array of strings:

```
function getFlagsValue<E extends {[k: string]: number | string}>(e: E, names: string[]) {
  let flags = 0;
  for (const name of names) {
    flags |= e[name] as number;
  }
  return flags;
}

// Example:
console.log(getFlagsValue(CookieOptions, ['Necessary', 'Marketing']));
// => 5
```